# Use noUiSlider to update hidden inputs with different formats than what is displayed

Tags: javascript, nouislider

I am using noUiSlider as an interface to update a range of values to be used in a search form. I want to display formatted numbers to the user but when the form is submitted I want to use non-formatted numbers.

I created some hidden inputs that are what actually gets submitted with the form and have tried to use an input mask to remove the formatting. This works on page load but once I start updating the range (either by using the slider or by using the inputs) the formatting does not get removed from the hidden input values anymore.

I am not sure if using hidden inputs for the un-formatted values is the way to go but its where I am at right now.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sliderPrice = document.getElementById('slider-price');

    var priceFromDisplay = document.getElementById('_pricefrom-display');
    var priceToDisplay = document.getElementById('_priceto-display');
    var inputsPriceDisplay = [priceFromDisplay, priceToDisplay];

    var priceFromHidden = document.getElementById('_pricefrom');
    var priceToHidden = document.getElementById('_priceto');
    var inputsPriceHidden = [priceFromHidden, priceToHidden];


    noUiSlider.create(sliderPrice, {
        start: [0, 55000],
        connect: true,
        step: 1000,
        behaviour: 'snap',
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 55000
        },
        format: wNumb({
            decimals: 0,
            prefix: '$',
            thousand: ','
        }),
    });

    sliderPrice.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
        inputsPriceDisplay[handle].value = values[handle];
        inputsPriceHidden[handle].value = values[handle];
    });

    inputsPriceDisplay.forEach(function (input, handle) {
        input.addEventListener('change', function () {
            sliderPrice.noUiSlider.setHandle(handle, this.value);
        });
        input.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            var values = sliderPrice.noUiSlider.get();
            var value = Number(values[handle]);
            var steps = sliderPrice.noUiSlider.steps();
            var step = steps[handle];
            var position;
            switch (e.which) {

                case 13:
                    sliderPrice.noUiSlider.setHandle(handle, this.value);
                    break;
                case 38:
                    position = step[1];
                    if (position === false) {
                        position = 1;
                    }
                    if (position !== null) {
                        sliderPrice.noUiSlider.setHandle(handle, value + position);
                    }
                    break;
                case 40:
                    position = step[0];
                    if (position === false) {
                        position = 1;
                    }
                    if (position !== null) {
                        sliderPrice.noUiSlider.setHandle(handle, value - position);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
    $('.unformat').mask('0000000');
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="_pricefrom-display" name="_pricefrom-display" value>
<input type="hidden" id="_pricefrom" name="_pricefrom" value class="unformat">

<input type="text" id="_priceto-display" name="_priceto-display" value>
<input type="hidden" id="_priceto" name="_priceto" value class="unformat">
```

For example, if the user uses the slider or types into the displayed input fields a range of $20,500 to $35,000 I want what the user sees to be formatted but what gets submitted to the form is 20500 to 35000.

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to every noUiSlider event contains the slider values without formatting applied. If you set that value to the hidden inputs, you can leave out the input masking. In your example:

```
sliderPrice.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle, unencoded) {
    inputsPriceDisplay[handle].value = values[handle];
    inputsPriceHidden[handle].value = unencoded[handle];
});
```